# USSD not returning data if not English

Tags: encoding, ussd

I have E180 Huawei GSM modem. I need to use USSD code to get some info from operator. I use this command 
    -----  at+cusd=1,"*225#",15 -----------

- It works very well for all USSD codes that return English results. But , when the USSD code regturn is in Arabic , then modem returns only OK , and no more messages
- I tried different encoding using  AT+CSCS="GSM" , or AT+CSCS="UCS2" , and also changed the *225#  to UCS2 code (which is ) at+cusd=1,"2A99AC3602",15  >>> but same issue.
- one last thing, I have other modems, and USSD returns data correctly.

Thanks for support

Comment: same issue. Answer your question if solved pls.

Comment: did any one get a solution for this issue ? Thanks..